# Using CMFCToolBarImages in CMFCTaskPane

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

In my MFC MDI application I have 10 `CMFCToolBar` and each has separate imagelist(bitmap images).

I implemented task pane using `CMFCTaskPane` in which I am grouping same tasks or activities what the `CMFCToolbar` is doing.

Can I use/assign  each `CMFCToolbar` image list to the tasks coming under each group?

In `CMFCTaskPane` class I only have these methods:

- `BOOL SetIconList(HIMAGELIST hIcons)`
- `BOOL SetIconsList(UINT uiImageListResID, int cx, COLORREF clrTransparent = RGB(255, 0, 255))`

In `CMFCTaskPane` class we have an option to assign only one image list to the entire taskpane. There is no option to assign separate imagelist to each group and its tasks.

But I have 10 `CMFCToolbar` and 10 `CImageList`. How to use my toolbar images to achieve my requirement?

In this link [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16529/Simple-Menus-That-Display-Icons-Minimalistic-Appro?msg=1895336](http://In%20this%20link%20https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16529/Simple-Menus-That-Display-Icons-Minimalistic-Appro?msg=1895336)

the toolbar images are used in the menu by overriding DrawItem() function similarly can we draw icon for a task by overriding the function

virtual void OnDrawTasks(CDC* pDC, CRect rectWorkArea); in the `CMFCTaskPane`.

I dont have any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you call LoadToolbar, you create local instance of imagelist for this toolbar.
By default, all toolbars in application shares same imagelist. So, just make something like this:

```
CMFCToolbar m_toolbar;
...
m_toolbar.Create(this, AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;);
int newIconID = CMFCToolBar::GetImages()->AddIcon(hIcon, TRUE);
m_toolbar.InsertButton(cmd, newIconID, name);
```